# Display input depending of login - PHP

Tags: php

I have a form with some inputs, I want to display only 1 input for each different login when I am logged in the system, I thought about using IF and ELSE, but I don't know how to use it, can someone help me?

I'm trying like this

```
<?php 
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$senha = $_SESSION['senha'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE login ='$login' AND senha = '$senha'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
{  
    $class = $cont['class'];
}

$codigo_relatorio = $_GET['codigo_relatorio'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM relatorio WHERE codigo_relatorio = '$codigo_relatorio' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

   if ($class == "adm") {
        echo '
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Educação Física - Arquivo:</b></b></label>
          <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadsed/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?></a>

          <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="fileed" multiple="" class="form-control-file" >
          </div>';
}
?>
```

Example: If you are logged in (educacao_fisica), you can only see the input of educacao_fisica ...

It continues to be shown to all logins ...

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You're on the right track, where are you having an issue?

Comment: You're not using `$_SESSION` correctly. A.) all pages using sessions should have `session_start()` at the beginning of the script. B.) Do not store credentials in session variables.

Comment: guys, thanks for the safety tips, but first I want to fix this, I await answers ...

Comment: As I stated earlier, it looks like you're on the right track, but your code (as it stands. now) will not work. What is your actual issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It worked, I put it at the beginning of the page::**

```
<?php  
// Iniciando a sessão
session_start();
if((!isset ($_SESSION['login']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['senha']) == true))
{
  unset($_SESSION['login']);
  unset($_SESSION['senha']);
  header('location:login.php');
  }

$logado = $_SESSION['login'];
?> .....
```

Thanks everyone for the tips!